# How to specify multiple style attributes in log4j2?

Tags: log4j2

The log4j2 reference for the %highlight Conversion Pattern ([here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html)) describes the syntax as `highlight{pattern}{style}`.  It refers to the `AnsiEscape` class ([here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/AnsiEscape.html)) for the colors/attributes, and even lists a summary.  But there is no indication how to specify multiple attributes to get the colors listed in the second row in the description of the Conversion Pattern, or how to specify both foreground and background colors for a single event level.  For example, how would I specify the `{style}` portion for Bright White foreground on a [normal] Green background for INFO level?

Answer (score 1):

It may a bit irretating when comparing the two PatternLayout Parameters

- %highlight{pattern}{style}
- %style{pattern}{style}

as were for `%highlight` the style is like:

```
%highlight{blabla}{FATAL=bg_red blinking bright yellow, ERROR=red, ...}
```

→ the combined attributes (for each level) are separated just by a spaces

but for `%style` it's like this:

```
%style{blabla}{bg_red, blinking, bright, yellow}
```

→ the combined attributes are separated by comma (with optional spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Separating the different attributes by spaces (for a given level) seems to work.  So to answer my own question, the `{style}` portion would be: `{INFO=bg_green bright white}`. Additional highlight specifications for other levels can follow before/after a comma.